# Yii2: Kartik FileInput Widget set id to catch events

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, kartik-v

I try to set the id for the Kartik FileInput Widget but it seems like it won't set it.. because I'm unable to catch the fileuploaded events after an successfull upload.
view.php

```
echo $form->field($ebook, 'imageFile')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'id'            => 'imageFile',
    'options'       => ['accept' => 'pdf/*'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowedFileExtensions' => ['pdf'],
        'showPreview'           => false,
        'showUpload'            => true,
        'uploadAsync'           => true,
        'uploadUrl'             => Url::to(['site/upload']),
    ]
]);
```

catchevent.js

```
$('#imageFile').on('fileuploaded', function(event, data, previewId, index) {
    var form = data.form, files = data.files, extra = data.extra,
        response = data.response, reader = data.reader;
    console.log('File uploaded triggered');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the id inside the option list:

```
echo $form->field($ebook, 'imageFile')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options'       => ['accept' => 'pdf/*', 'id' => 'imageFile',],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        // ...
    ]
]);
```

you can find it in the [docs](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput#comment-2705981552)